# Django: How to not return all model fields

Tags: python, django

I'm using a Django system where each model has an associated serializer (pretty standard).

In one model, the serializer is as follows:

```
class ThingSerializer(ModelSerializerWithFields):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = "__all__"
```

and a model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("a", "b")


    thing_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
    a = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    b = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

I want to implement a system that: if field `a` of `Thing` is not null, then field `b` is returned (on a `GET` request, for example), and if `a` is null then `b` is not returned.
How (and where) can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `to_representation()` method on your serializer. Like this:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if instance.a is None:
            del data['b']
        return data
```